# How to align the text with the image that is besides to it?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am struggling with aligning the text with the images that sits besides to it. I want to put an image with a text in the ASP.NET Ajax TabContainer (inside the TabPanel specifically) and I want this to works for this case and other cases. I searched a lot but most of the resources talked about special situations based on the height or width of the image. What about if I have more that one image with different dimensions.

**So could you please help me in giving me such a way for aligning the text with any image?**

My ASP.NET code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="ImagesGallery" runat="server" OnDemandMode="Once" Enabled="true" >
        <HeaderTemplate><img src="images/New/image.png" class="icon" alt=""  /> Images Gallery</HeaderTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
```

My CSS that I tried to make it works is:

```
/* For aligning the image (icon) with the text */
.icon
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:middle;` on your image.
Here is an **example** with stackoverflow icon http://jsfiddle.net/tDfDP/
Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it and it works well with me. One more question, can I use this way with any image?

Comment: With every image you want to align in the middle yes :)